# Percentage Change of (A+B) different than percentage change of A + percentage change of B

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

Example problem.  Average number of actions for time period $x = 248$, average number of actions for time period $y = 310$.  Percentage change is $(310-248)/248 = 25\%$ increase.

The actions can be broken into two subgroups; $A$ and $B$.

Average number of $A$-actions for time period $X$ is $114$, average number of $A$-actions for time period $Y$ is $122$.  Percentage change is $(122-114)/114 = 7\%$ increase.

Average number of $B$-actions for time period $X$ is $134$, average number of $B$-actions for time period $y$ is $188$.  Percentage change is $(188-134)/134 = 42\%$ increase.

action $A$, time period $X$ plus action $B$, time period $X$ is $114 + 134 = 248$
action $B$, time period $Y$ plus action $B$, time period $Y$ is $122 + 188 = 310$

**But**

percentage change of action $A$ plus percentage change of action $B$ is $7\%+42\%=49\%$ and not the Percentage change of actions $A$ and $B$ together.  Why is this?

Comment: What happens if increment in $A$-actions is $10\%$ and increment in $B$-actions is $10\%$.  Would you expect an overall increment in actions of $10\%$ or $20\%$?

Comment: If A and B are subsets of the same data set, I'd expect an overall increment of 20%...hence my question...but now that I think about it the individual subsets percentage change is dependent on the size of that subgroup.  Since the A and B are not equal their percentage change doesn't necessarily have to equal the overall change?  Is an example of the Simpson's paradox?

Comment: It seems that is some kind of Simpson's paradox.  In my simplified example the overall increment is $10\%$.  The overall increment is a (weighted) mean of the individual increments, not the sum of those individual increments.

Comment: I think I was just confusing myself as it's a percentage change of an average.  The overall I mentioned above would be the weighted mean of the individual increments?  While the mean of the individual increments would be close, safe to say the weighted mean would be the more accurate choice?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to remember that the overall increment is some kind of mean of the individual increment.  The overall increment **is not** the sum of the individual increments.

Let's put some algebra on your example:

$a,c$ are number of $A$-actions in time periods $X$ and $Y$ respectively.
$b,d$ are number of $B$-actions in time periods $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

So, the increment in $A$, $r_A=\dfrac{c-a}a$.  Respectively the increment in $B$, $r_B=\dfrac{d-b}b$.

The sum of these increments (which is not the same as the overall increment) is:
$r_A+r_B=\dfrac{c-a}a+\dfrac{d-b}b$.

On the other hand, lets $p_A = \dfrac a{a+b}$ and $p_B = \dfrac b{a+b}$ where $p_A+p_B=1$, and let's calculate the weighted mean of $r_A$ and $r_B$:
\begin{align}
p_Ar_a+p_Br_B&=\frac a{a+b}\cdot\frac{c-a}a+\frac b{a+b}\cdot\frac{d-b}b
\\&=\frac{c-a}{a+b}+\frac{d-b}{a+b}
\\&=\frac{(c-a)+(d-b)}{a+b}
\\&=\frac{(c+d)-(a-b)}{a+b}
\end{align}

The overall increment of both $A$-actions and $B$-actions is $\dfrac{(c+d)-(a+b)}{a+b}$.

Let's see when both increments could be equal:
\begin{align}
r_A+r_B &= p_Ar_A+p_Br_B \\
r_A+(1-p_B)r_B &= p_Ar_A \\
r_A+p_Ar_B &= p_Ar_A \\
r_A &= p_Ar_A-p_Ar_B
\end{align}
Note that $0\le p_A\le1$ (equality only if $a=0$ or $b=0$ respectively), so in any non-trivial case $a\ne0$ and $b\ne0$, then $0<p_A<1$.

For a positive increment $r_A$, then $r_A>p_Ar_A$.  If $r_B$ is also positive, then $p_Ar_A>p_Ar_A+p_Ar_B$ therefor $r_A>p_Ar_A-p_Ar_B$ and $r_A\ne p_Ar_A-p_Ar_B$.  A similar analysis will hold if both increments are negative.  So the only chances that the sum of increments are equal to the overall increment are certain special cases in which increments cancel eachother.

In the general case *overall increment **is not** the sum of increments*.

Comment: Carlos - you da man!